# force cancel current crawl

Tags: 2010, crawl, searchserviceapplication

Is there a way to fully cancel a search crawl via Powershell or Central Administration? I have a current crawl going and it is sitting at 1209:04:57 for the duration. It has been in the `Stopping` status for over 2 hours.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue @kevorski?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the Search Application and created a new one

Answer (score 4):

## Stop the crawl for all content sources

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication "Search Service Application" | ForEach-Object { 
If($_.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle")
{
    Write-Host "Stopping crawl on Content source $($_.Name)..." 
    $_.StopCrawl() 

    While ($_.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle")
 {
        Write-Host "Waiting to crawl to be stopped..." -f DarkYellow
        sleep 3
    }
    write-host "Crawl Stopped Successfully!" -f DarkGreen
}
else
{
    write-host "Crawl Status of the Content source '$($_.Name)' is Idle!" -f DarkGreen
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try restarting the search service.

- go to services
- restart "SharePoint Server Search 14" service

If you got multiple servers with search service you need to do this on each server.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication "Search Service Application" | ForEach-Object { If($_.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle") { Write-Host "Stopping crawl on Content source $($_.Name)..." $_.StopCrawl() While ($_.CrawlStatus -ne "Idle") { Write-Host "Waiting to crawl to be stopped..." -f DarkYellow sleep 3 } write-host "Crawl Stopped Successfully!" -f DarkGreen } else { write-host "Crawl Status of the Content source '$($_.Name)' is Idle!" -f DarkGreen } }
```

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/05/force-stop-sharepoint-search-crawl-using-powershell.html#ixzz4mkAV4BnY

if this is not working try this

```
net stop OSearch14
net start OSearch14
```

Comment: I used this script, but it is still sitting at `stopping`

Comment: check the edit answer

Comment: When I attempt to start the service it tells me the requested service has already been started

Comment: thats fine, but what is the status of the crawl?

Comment: It is still crawling

Comment: how many server you have in the farm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62171/discussion-between-kevorski-and-waqas-sarwar-mvp).